# Trim SQL field and use ISNULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, export

fairly new to SQL and having problems with trimming the data when using in an `ISNULL` statement

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(CA.CUSTNMBR)) as AccountNumber
```

The above gives me the account number without spaces (correct)

```
,ISNULL(NAN.SageAccountNo, LTRIM(RTRIM(CA.CUSTNMBR))) AS AccountNumber
```

I then tried to use the same principle in the above `ISNULL` statement but it returns the correct column but doesn't trim the data.

Comment: I agree that this looks like it should work. Probably a question for Microsoft. Have you tried `COALESE(NAN.SageAccountNo, LTRIM(RTRIM(CA.CUSTNMBR))) AS AccountNumber` to select the first non-NULL?

Comment: What is the dataype of `SageAccountNo` is it fixed width `char` or `nchar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(COALESCE(NAN.SageAccountNo, CA.CUSTNMBR))) as AccountNumber
```

This will trim either `SageAccountNo` or `CUSTNMBR`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `LTRIM(RTRIM(` outside the `ISNULL`:

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(NAN.SageAccountNo, CA.CUSTNMBR)))
```

Comment: Thank you knew it would be something so simple :)